# Spring Boot JUnit test case to test custom exception is throwing AssertionError instead of CustomException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, junit, custom-exceptions

I am testing a Spring boot MVC application which takes MultipartFile as input. My service class will throw a custom exception when the file format is other than .json. I've written a JUnit test case which tests this scenario.

Instead of throwing my custom exception `(expected = FileStorageException.class)` my test case is throwing an `AssertionError`.

How to resolve this issue and validate the exception message using `.andExpect(content().string("Wrong file format. Allowed: JSON."))`

**Exception**

09:36:48.327 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
com.test.util.exception.FileStorageException: Wrong file format. Allowed: JSON.

**Code**

```
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration(classes = WebConfig.class, initializers = ConfigFileApplicationContextInitializer.class)
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class UploadTest
{

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext webApplicationContext;

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Before
  public void setup()
  {
    mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(webApplicationContext).build();
  }

  /**
   * 
   */
  public UploadTest()
  {
    // default constructor
  }

  @Test(expected = FileStorageException.class)
  // @Test(expected= AssertionError.class)
  public void testInvalidFileFormat() throws Exception
  {
    try
    {
      MockMultipartFile testInput = new MockMultipartFile("file", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "some json".getBytes());
      mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/uploadFile").file(testInput))
          // .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError()).andExpect(content().string("Wrong
          // file format. Allowed: JSON."))
          .andDo(print());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      fail(e.toString());
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit only knows about exceptions that are thrown by the test method (in your example `testInvalidFileFormat()`. Therefore it only can check these exceptions.

You're catching every exception that is thrown by `mockMvc.perform(...)` and instead throw an `AssertionError` from the line

```
fail(e.toString());
```

This is the `AssertionError` that you see in your test result.

If you want to test exceptions then you must not catch them within your test:

```
@Test(expected = FileStorageException.class)
public void testInvalidFileFormat() throws Exception
{
  MockMultipartFile testInput = new MockMultipartFile(
    "file", "filename.txt", "text/plain", "some json".getBytes()
  );
  mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.multipart("/uploadFile").file(testInput))
      // .andExpect(status().isInternalServerError()).andExpect(content().string("Wrong
      // file format. Allowed: JSON."))
      .andDo(print());
}
```

By the way you don't need to explicitly add the default constructor and can remove the lines

```
/**
 * 
 */
public UploadTest()
{
    // default constructor
}
```

It is called default constructor because it is automatically there.